# Ui-select is not working with more then one field on same html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-select

I am using ui-select on two fields but not able to manipulate it  because its showing first field blank even I checked value with data-model and that is showing there even if I am adding new value its still showing in data-model but not in input box and the second field is showing both first and second fields value.
    Below are the both object which I am using for UI rendering

```
columnsTagObj.displayColumns = {
             Name=[1],  
             Group= "DDR",
             Class= "inactivated",
             Candidates= ["ostine"], 
             sourcePMID= ["322222", "Altretamine"] 
            }

        Columns =  [{"subtype": "drugName", "tag": "Name", "type": "appendingField", "caption": "Name"},{"subtype": "drugName", "tag": "Candidates", "type": "appendingField", "caption": "Candidates"}]

<div ng-if="colValues.type == 'appendingField'">   
<div ng-if="colValues.subtype =='drugName'">      <ui-select multiple n-d="ng-model="columnsTagObj.displayColumns[colValues.tag]"    theme="selectize" ng-  disabled="disabled" required>  
<ui-select-match>{{$item}}</ui-select-match>  <ui-select-choices refresh="getDrugNameList($select.search)" refresh-delay="0" repeat="item in Druglist | filter:$select.search">
                                         {{item}}
                                     </ui-select-choices>
                                 </ui-select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: [Please do not post images of code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Provide your code, proper html and javascript you are using.

Comment: @ManojLodhi I got the issue it was happening due to theme once I changed it to bootstrap it start working.